# Pickle error multiprocessing between Python 3.6.3 and 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

My code is running completely fine on Python 3.5.2, but when I use Python 3.6.3 (without changing a single line of code) I get a pickle error from multiprocessing and I am not sure why.

> TypeError: can't pickle "MyClass instance" objects

Any idea why ?
Thanks !

Comment: show your MyClass ?

Comment: MyClass is from a library so I can't really show it, but I don't understand why the instance of this class would be pickable in a version of python and not in another one :/ @PatrickArtner

Comment: [changes 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html) does not mention less pickle-ability, only improvements ...

Comment: Just mention the library, version, and class name.

Comment: The library is pachi_py (https://github.com/openai/pachi-py), and the instance is what is returned by pachi_py.CreateBoard()

Comment: Yes, thats what I saw as well, thats why I came here! @PatrickArtner

Comment: You can reproduce the error by just installing the module that I linked above, import pickle, import pachi_py and try pickle.dumps(pachi_py.CreateBoard(10)) ! Works on Python 3.5.2 but not on Python 3.6.3